# MySQL Table Join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables as

#### tbl_student

```
student_id  student_name     student_address
1           Mark Anderson    Park Avenue #203 CA
```

#### tbl_student_subjects

```
RecordID fkStudentID fkSubject
1           1         English
2           1         Zoology
3           1         Botany
```

How can I get the student details with all its subject with a single join and student details should not be repeated.

Thanks in advance
Umar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select student_id, student_name, student_address, GROUP_CONCAT(fkSubject)
from tbl_student
left join tbl_student_subjects ON tbl_student.student_id = tbl_student_subjects.fkStudentID
group by tbl_student.student_id
```

[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) docs. Note that it's length-limited, by default, to 1024 characters, so if you've got any overachiever students whose class details will exceed 1024 characters, the extra class information will get silently dropped.

Comment: Dear Sir,Many Many thanks for your help. This works for me when I need the subjects only with each student, but if I need more attributes also like subject code from subjects table, how can I get the subject code attribute also?

Comment: just add it to the query. if you need to directly relate the subject and codes, then something like `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(fkSubject, ' ', extra, fields, here))` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

**Something like this**

```
SELECT tbl_student.student_name, tbl_student.student_address, tbl_student_subjects.fksubject 
FROM tbl_student 
INNER JOIN tbl_student_subjects ON tbl_student_subjects.fkstudentID = tbl_student.student_id
WHERE 1=1 
GROUP BY tbl_student.student_id
```